# Building joint probability distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

So if I have the random variables X and Y that both assumes the sames values and I know the probability for each value $P_X(x)$ and $P_Y(y)$, how can I build the joint probability distribution for the discrete case?

I`ve tried using $$p_X(x) = \sum_{y} p(x, y) $$ to build a linear system and use the symmetry to solve it, but it did not work.

Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint distribution is not determined from the marginals. There's an infinite set of solutions.

Consider the following example of two binary variables $X$ and $Y$ whose joint distribution $p(x,y)$ is as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
p(0,0) &= 0.2 \\
p(1,0) &= 0.4 \\
p(0,1) &= 0.1 \\
p(1,1) &= 0.3
\end{split}
$$
As you can find, the marginal distributions are $p_X(x=1) = 0.7$ and $p_Y(y=1) = 0.4.$

However, those marginals are also true of the joint distribution
$q(x,y) = p_X(x) p_Y(y).$ As you can easily see, $q(x,y) \ne p(x,y)$ but they share the same marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y.$

Comment: Basically, a joint distribution contains information on the marginal distributions *and* the dependency of the random variables. $~$ So, *since* they lack that information on dependency, a pair of marginal distributions *alone* is insufficient to reconstruct their variables' joint distribution.